# Mantel-Byar test and Simon-Makuch plot for survival analysis with time-dependent covariate in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to conduct a survival analysis with a time-dependent covariate using the [Mantel-Byar test](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1974.10480131) and then adding the [Simon-Makuch survival plot](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/mpr.124/abstract) in R, using the [Rcmdr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RcmdrPlugin.EZR/versions/1.33/topics/Mantel.Byar) package.

Unfortunately the corresponding R documentation is not complete and I am stuck.

The corresponding mock dataset is the following:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
death <- c(0, 1, 0, 1)
death_days <- c(31, 59, 46, 41)
nonfatal_event <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)
nonfatal_event_days <- c(31, 51, 41, 41)
dataset <- data.frame(id, death, death_days, nonfatal_event, nonfatal_event_days)
```

How should I proceed further?

Comment: I don't understand the difficulty. What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out that after installing the `Rcmdr` and the `RcmdrPlugin.EZR` packages, I needed to call the `Rcmdr` package, then call the `RcmdrPlugin.EZR` from the Tools menu.

Then, I needed to load the dataset, call the Cox proportional hazard regression with time-dependent covariate, and finally call first the Mantel-Byar test and then the Simon-Makuch plot.

A sample code is provided below, which can be directly called in R Commander.

```
#####Cox proportional hazard regression with time-dependent covariate#####
library(survival, pos=15)
library(aod, pos=16)
TempDF <- Dataset
TempTD <- stsplit(TempDF, TempDF$death_days, TempDF$death, 
  TempDF$nonfatal_event_days, TempDF$nonfatal_event, TempDF$death_days)
CoxModel.1 <- coxph(Surv(start_td, stop_td, endpoint_td==1) ~ covariate_td, 
  data=TempTD, method="breslow")
res <- NULL
(res <- summary(CoxModel.1))
cox.table <- NULL
cox.table <- signif(cbind(t(res$conf.int[,c(1,3,4)]), 
  p.value=res$coefficients[,5]), digits=4)
rownames(cox.table) <- rownames(res$coefficients)
colnames(cox.table) <- gettext(domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.EZR",c("Hazard ratio", 
  "Lower 95%CI", "Upper 95%CI", "p.value"))
cox.table
waldtest(CoxModel.1)
windows(width=7, height=7); par(lwd=1, las=1, family="sans", cex=1, 
  mgp=c(3.0,1,0))
oldpar <- par(oma=c(0,0,3,0), mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(cox.zph(CoxModel.1), df=2)
par(oldpar)
print(cox.zph(CoxModel.1))

#####Mantel-Byer test#####
Mantel.Byar(Group = "covariate_td", Event = TempTD$endpoint_td, 
StartTime = TempTD$start_td, StopTime = TempTD$stop_td, 
method = c("SAS", "Tominaga"), plot=0, landmark=0)

#####Simon-Makuch plot#####
Mantel.Byar(Group = "covariate_td", Event = TempTD$endpoint_td, 
StartTime = TempTD$start_td, StopTime = TempTD$stop_td, 
method = c("SAS", "Tominaga"), plot=1, landmark=0)
```

Comment: can i ask how you loaded the packages Rcmdr and the plugin ? I have an issue by doing the library(Rcmdr) it never ends, and with what you said it seems you did something special to load them. (how to call from Tools menu)